# How Nothing can be subclass of all types when multiple inheritance is not supported in scala

Tags: scala

This is more of conceptual question i stumbled upon. Scala states than multiple inheritance is not supported but at same time states than "Nothing" is subclass of all types. Isn't this against the concept that Scala states.

Comment: `Nothing` is not a _subclass_ of all types, it is a _subtype_ of all types.

Comment: @Michael Zajac, but isn't subclassing is a kind of subtyping. What exactly is the difference between them.

Comment: Exactly, subclassing is a kind of subtyping. One that allows multiple inheritance, in contrast to subclassing.

Comment: Thanks man that helped.

Comment: Subclassing creates a subtying relationship, but you can create a subtyping relationship without subclassing. For example, `Option[String]` is a subtype of `Option[Any]`, but a subclass isn't needed to define that.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Zajac. That was to the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Scala states than multiple inheritance is not supported

That is not true. Scala supports linearized multiple mixin inheritance.

> but at same time states than "Nothing" is subclass of all types.

That is not true. [The documentation](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html) clearly states that `Nothing extends Any`, and that's it. It is only a subclass of `Any`, and nothing else.

The documentation *also* states (**bold** emphasis mine):

> `Nothing` is a **subtype** of every other type (including `scala.Null`)

As you can see, nowhere does the documentation say that `Nothing` is a sub**class** of all types. It only says it is a sub**type** of all types, which is completely different.

> Isn't this against the concept that Scala states.

No, it is not.

But even *if* what you are saying *were* true, there is still no contradiction: the Scala Language Specification defines what "Scala" is, and if the SLS says that `Nothing` is a subclass of all classes, then that's how it is. The Scala Language Specification say anything it wants, and this will never be against the concepts of Scala, because the Scala Language Specification *defines* the concepts of Scala.

Now, as it turns out, your premise was wrong, and the Scala Language Specification does *not* say that `Nothing` has multiple superclasses, but it *could* say that if it *wanted*, and that would *not* be against the concepts of Scala, because the Scala Language Specification says what, exactly, the concepts of Scala are.

Comment: @ Jörg W Mittag, Thanks buddy. I got confused between Type and Class but above explanation cleared that all.